# Pagination throws 404

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pagination, urls, 404-error

I'm experiencing some problems with my pagination when displaying custom post types. I would like to display 9 posts and then display a numeric pagination. This is working, some links are generated with (for me) correct URLs : http://mywebsite/tutorial/page/2 or http://mywebsite/tutorial/taxonomy/page/2 but it always finish on a 404 page.

Any idea is welcome, the following is my code so if you see any problem :)

Thanks by advance.

Cyril

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'tutorial',
        'paged' => ((get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
        'posts_per_page' => 9
    );
    query_posts($args);
?>

[MAIN LOOP]

<?php numeric_pagination(); ?>
```

Here is the numeric_pagination() function (found on the web, working on another website...) :

```
function numeric_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2) {
global $paged;
$showitems = ($range * 2) + 1;
if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;
if($pages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        if(!$pages) {
            $pages = 1;
        }
}   

if(1 != $pages) {
    echo '<div class="numeric-pagination"><p>';
    if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo '<a href="'.get_pagenum_link(1).'">&laquo;</a>';
    if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo '<a href="'.get_pagenum_link($paged - 1).'">&lsaquo;</a>';

    for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
            echo ($paged == $i)? '<span class="current">'.$i.'</span>':'<a href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'" class="inactive" >'.$i.'</a>';
        }
    }

    if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo '<a href="'.get_pagenum_link($paged + 1).'">&rsaquo;</a>';  
    if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo '<a href="'.get_pagenum_link($pages).'">&raquo;</a>';
    echo '</p></div>';
}
```

}

There is maybe a problem with my custom post type and my taxonomies so I give also the code for that :

```
/* POST TYPE */

add_action('init','create_tutorials_post_type');
function create_tutorials_post_type() {
    // Labels
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Tutorials',
        'singular_name' => 'Tutorial',
        'add_new' => 'Add new',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add new tutorial',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit',
        'new_item' => 'New tutorial',
        'view_item' => 'View tutorial',
        'search_items' => 'Search tutorial',
        'not_found' =>  'No tutorial found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No tutorial found in trash', 
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Tutorials'
    );
    // Arguments
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'show_in_menu' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments')
    );
    // Register post type
    register_post_type('tutorial',$args);
}

/* TAXONOMY */

add_action('init','create_tutorials_taxonomies');
function create_tutorials_taxonomies() {
    // Labels
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Tutorial types',
        'singular_name' => 'Tutorial type',
        'search_items' => 'Search a type',
        'all_items' => 'All types',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent type',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent type:',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit type', 
        'update_item' => 'Update type',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add new type',
        'new_item_name' => 'New tutorial type',
        'menu_name' => 'Types'
    );
    // Arguments
    $args =  array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'tutorials', 'hierarchical' => true)
    );
    // Register taxonomy
    register_taxonomy('tutorial_type',array('tutorial'),$args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change predefined posts_per_page to minimum value in wordpress settings or add code below to functions.php. Wordpress using default parameter. For example: 10. And if your settings in query_posts or WP_Query look like "posts_per_page=>2" and number of posts in custom post type less then 10, after clicking to /page/2/ you will redirected to page 404.

Use this code for functions.php for solve problem:

```
if( !is_admin() ){  
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts',  'set_per_page'  );
}
function set_per_page( $query ) {
    global $wp_the_query;
    if($query->is_post_type_archive('tutorial')&&($query === $wp_the_query)){
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1);
    }
  return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had a similar issue.

The problem was WordPress is setup to show 10 posts per page by default which clashed with my query (limiting it to 2 posts) to fix the issue I changed the WordPress setting (Settings / Reading in the admin dashboard) to 1.

Comment: Thank you but I already tried this and the problem is still there :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [paginate_links()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) for this:

```
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
```

This is the latest and greatest example from the codex article linked above. It's generally better to leverage a core function whenever the opportunity is available.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using parse_query filter.
For details take a look here:
[Fix custom query pagination without changing site-wide posts-per-page settings](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27184/fix-custom-query-pagination-without-changing-site-wide-posts-per-page-settings/28624#28624)

Comment: unfortunately this is not working... but it's a good solution to fix this problem if you just need to change de site-wide posts per page setting

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but if someone runs in to this problem please try the following:

Set the 'posts_per_page = x' in your php code to the same value as Reading Settings inside the admin area. So if 'posts_per_page = 3', Reading settings 'Blog pages show at most' should also be set to 3.