# Fix custom query pagination without changing site-wide posts-per-page settings

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, loop

Many people report problems with pagination of custom queries or custom post type archives: url/page/2 produces a 404 even though all the setup is correct.

Many end up figuring out that this is occurring because the posts_per_page of their custom loop is less than the maximum posts per page setting in the admin, which they fix by changing

```
 Settings » Reading » "Blog pages show at most: ____ posts"
```

to 1.

This works in my situation, but I would much prefer to change this only for this specific custom query, rather than the whole site. Is this possible?

The relevant WP_Query is this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'publication',
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'paged'=>$paged));
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a custom post type: publication

in functions.php place that code:

```
function mk_parse_query($query) {
  if ($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'publication')) {
        set_query_var( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
  }
}
if( !is_admin() ) {
    add_filter('parse_query','mk_parse_query');
}
```

Similar code works for me, but in my case I was struggling with 404 on custom taxonomies paged urls.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it to the post type publication globally then use the `pre_get_posts` hook and add the following to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
  if ( 'publication' === $query->query_vars['post_type'] && ! is_admin() ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
  }
} );
```

If you need it for only one custom query than the following answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20905538/2043492