# WooCommerce custom query and paging: Not Found error

Tags: plugins, theme-development, pagination, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm experiencing a problem with the following piece code:

```
global $wp_query;

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$filter_args['paged'] = $paged;
$filter_args['posts_per_page'] = 2;

$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, $filter_args );
query_posts( $args );
```

This code is located at **archive-prodcut.php** file, inside of my theme/woocommerce folder.

It works correctly in order to show first 2 products and also to show WooCommerce pagination on the bottom.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
```

However, when I click on each of the pages I'm getting a "Not found" error. When I tried putting an echo on the top of the archive-prodcut.php file I realized that it doesn't load. The url looks like www.site.com/product-category/cat-name/page/2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Research this site archives for `wp_query` and `pagination`, lots of Q&A's about this

Comment: Why do you need to `query_posts` anyway?  That is well known to mess with pagination and the query is already set to show an archive of products on the `archive-product.php` template.  If you just want to alter the number of posts per page for products then look into `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: I need to do that since there are a couple of filters to be applied (not shown in the code above). @brasofilo, thanks for your suggestion, but I'm unable to find a topic that covers and resolves my problem.

Comment: Maybe if you show the filters you'd like to apply there is an alternative with `pre_get_posts`?

Comment: Same issues with pre_get_posts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the posts_per_page being 2 and the backend WordPress Settings being a greater value.  If you set your WordPress Settings to 2 it will work. But you may not want all your pages to have two posts.  In that case you can alter the query using the code in this answer, [Pagination Throws 404](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41266/26475) just for that archive page.

Here is the code to put in your theme's function.php file.

```
if( !is_admin() ){  
add_action( 'pre_get_posts',  'set_per_page'  );
}
function set_per_page( $query ) {
    global $wp_the_query;
    if($query->is_post_type_archive('product')&&($query === $wp_the_query)){
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1);
    }
  return $query;
}
```

This changes the posts_per_page before running your query. Then when you get your posts it has your query with the dynamic variable posts_per_page. So if that number is 3, you will get your 3 products per page and no 404 error.

Comment: It's actually a dynamic variable, I used 2 just for example purposes. It's a value taken from a form with all filters applied via $_GET.

Comment: Right, so you still have the problem that if they enter a number lower than what is set in WordPress -> Settings -> Reading -> Max Number of Posts then you are going to get the 404.  Use the code from the answer and replace tutorial with product in is_post_type_archive. The posts_per_page, 1 in the answer changes the WordPress Reading Settings only if the query is on archive-product.php.

Comment: That would work only if I'll able to get the $_GET data at this point and use it. Thanks, I'll try that later today.

Comment: You don't need the variable for the code in the answer, just in your query on the archive-product.php page.  The set_per_page function doesn't need a variable, leave that at 1 and put that function in your theme's functions.php file. I edited my answer above to explain it better.

Comment: @ellenmva thanks a million, your snipper really saved me, well done